# Need help understanding the early visual system towards a scale invariant representation

Tags: vision, theoretical-neuroscience

My research team is looking at understanding how the brain makes a scale and rotation invariant representation of objects.
We are composed of computer scientists and are a little ignorant on modern neuroscience.

Currently, we understand that the retina samples in a log-polar fashion.
This log polar sampling on its own is scale and rotation invariant, up to a horizontal or vertical shift in the log-polar representation/plot.
However, we are working on modelling what happens to the visual input signal past the retinal-thalamic connection.
To our understanding, as the visual signal reaches V1, and goes through V2 and V4, there is repeated log-polar sub-sampling occurring.

We have been developing some visualization program to model what we know of how the system works.
So for example, we are able to generate a log-polar frame of given dimensions and parameters, (much like what is done in this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12559-016-9430-8) and then sampling with on or off center receptive fields to represent the retinal layer.

After sampling from an input image, we generate a 'compressed cartesian' representation of the image, where we remove spatial information mimicking how we think the signal would be passed and compressed through the optic nerve and enacting cortical magnification.
Then we'd repeat this multiple times in a sensory processing hierarchy, with different log-polar parameters, representing the different layers of the visual system.
In the interest of time, I have below a crude sample of an input checkerboard pattern. I can update with a better image in some time, but the first layer represents the retina, the second V1, and so on (the chosen parameters are not bio-fidelic, we'd be reducing in image dimensions on a good run of the program). The first column represents the signal that the layer is receiving (the blue indicates the visual field), the second is the compressed cartesian representation after sampling, and the third column is the log polar representation.
[image]

So, is this really a good way to model how it works?

Further, we've noticed that repeated log-polar sampling causes cortical magnification that distorts in a manner kind of like a lens. We were wondering if anyone has viewed the propagation of visual signals with an optic lens analogy before.
Any pointers to references would be greatly appreciated.